# Inline Vue JS object inside tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I put inside a HTML tag like this my object?

```
<a href="javascript:parent.call('{{ value.text }}','1','','2','3');">
```

The object is inside a loop from a Json parser.

Thank you

Comment: Where does `value.text` come from? Also, interpolation is not allowed in attributes in Vue 2. You need to use the binding syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<a :href="`javascript:parent.call('${ value.text }','1','','2','3');`">
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue 2.0 does not allow interpolation inside attributes, you have to use the binding syntax:

```
<a v-bind:href="`javascript:parent.call(${ value.text },'1','','2','3');`">
```

or in short:

```
<a :href="`javascript:parent.call(${ value.text },'1','','2','3');`">
```

As a side note, it is preferable to keep the html clean and move this to a computed:

```
<a :href="link">

computed: {
    link() {
       return `javascript:parent.call(${ this.value.text },'1','','2','3');`
    }
}
```